# Need suggestion on Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: c#

I'm trying to segregate few properties from the parent abstract class which are not common among all of the children.

But my parent is accessing some of the uncommon abstract method from one of it's property's setter. And this situation is blocking me to use the ISP.

```
public abstract class Parent
    {
        public abstract string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public abstract string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public abstract void Test();

        //Non abstract property
        public string MyProperty3
        {
            get { return ""; }

            set { Test(); }
        }
    }

    //Now Kid1 and Kid2 absolutely need all the parent components. So let see the Kid3 now...
    //Kid3 will not in need of all the parent components.
    public class Kid3 : Parent
    {
        public override string MyProperty1
        {
            get
            {
                return "";
            }

            set
            {
                /*Do something*/
            }
        }

        // this is not needed for Kid3 but forced to implement
        public override string MyProperty2
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        // this is not needed for Kid3 but forced to implement
        public override void Test()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

So, I remove the Myproperty2 and the Test() method from parent and moved to an interface like below.

```
public interface ICommonMembers
{
    string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    void TestMethod();
}

public class Kid1 : Parent, ICommonMembers { }
public class Kid2 : Parent, ICommonMembers { }
public class Kid3 : Parent { }
```

**Now the issue arise**
Since I removed the Test() from Parent class, the Myproperty3's setter is giving me an error.

Comment: You need to introduce `CommonParent` which implements `ICommonMembers` and then make `Parent` derived from `CommonParent`. Then `Kid3` can derive from `CommonParent` and `Kid1` and `Kid2` derive from `Parent`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Whooo! It helps me alot ... Thank you ... But there is an another issue ... My "Parent" class is already deriving from an abstract class and other interfaces ... So I cannot derive **Commonparent** again because we cannot derive multiple classes right !
Also I cannot derive **ICommonMembers** because I should not make them as abstract since Kid3 is not needed them..

Thanks again ...